# How to pass the request body to an Azure SQL stored procedure using Azure Functions JavaScript model v4?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions with JavaScript / Node.js model v4 and am trying to pass the request body to a SQL Server stored procedure.
It seems impossible to pass the request body as described below.

I have an SqlInput setup like this:

```
const sp_location_insert = input.sql({
    commandText: 'dbo.sp_location_insert',
    parameters: '@Body={body}',
    commandType: 'StoredProcedure',
    connectionStringSetting: 'SqlConnectionString',
})
```

and a function defined like this:

```
app.http('locationPost', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    route: 'location',
    extraInputs: [sp_location_insert],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const body = await request.json()
        context.log(`body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`)
        const response = context.extraInputs.get(sp_location_insert)
        const location_id = response[0]["location_id"]
        return {    status: 201,
                    body: location_id
        }
    }
})
```

The error message that I get is this:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'body'.

I have experimented with many things including removing `async` and `await` in the handler, using `request.body` instead of `request.json()` and trying to initialize `body`
before awaiting `request.json()`.  Nothing seems to work.   I had hoped this would work because if I have seen this technique
work with request parameters.   The problem seems to be that request body must be awaited for while the `extraInput` is evaluated as soon as the function is invoked.

Microsoft have posted a partial answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1511205/how-can-i-pass-the-request-body-to-a-stored-proced?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1437825#newest-answer-comment but that solution only allows a simple text string in the request body - no JSON.  (Check the comments in the question.)

Is there a way that I can pass a JSON request body to an SQL Server stored procedure using JavaScript Azure Functions model v4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest answer seems to be from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1511205/how-can-i-pass-the-request-body-to-a-stored-proced?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1437825#newest-answer-comment as follows:

```
const sp_sampletest = input.sql({
    commandText: 'dbo.InsertTextAndReturn',
    parameters: '@InputText={text}',
    commandType: 'StoredProcedure',
    connectionStringSetting: 'SqlConnectionString',
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    extraInputs: [sp_sampletest],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const response = context.extraInputs.get(sp_sampletest);
        return { jsonBody: response };
    }
});
```

Then request like this:

```
POST http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "text": "simple string"
}
```

However, this will not allow further JSON to be included at "simple string" - just a "simple string".   See the comments in the original post on MS Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the two methods below to pass the request body to an Azure SQL stored procedure using Azure Functions.

**Method-1 :**

***Code :***

```js
const { ConnectionPool } = require('mssql');
const axios = require('axios');

const config = {
    server: "<server_name>.database.windows.net",
    database: "<db_name>",
    user: "<user_name>",
    password: "<password>",
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        connectTimeout: 30000,
    },
};

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {
        let body;

        if (req.body) {
            body = req.body;
            context.log(`Incoming request body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
        } else {
            body = { someExpectedProperty: "1" };
            context.log(`Direct function invocation with body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
        }

        if (!body || !body.someExpectedProperty) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: 'Bad Request: Missing or invalid request body.',
            };
            return;
        }

        const pool = new ConnectionPool(config);

        try {
            await pool.connect();
            context.log('Connected to the database');

            const request = pool.request();

            const query = `EXEC dbo.sp_location_insert @ColumnName = N'${body.someExpectedProperty}'`;
            const result = await request.query(query);

            if (result && result.recordset && result.recordset[0] && result.recordset[0].location_id) {
                const location_id = result.recordset[0].location_id;

                context.res = {
                    status: 201,
                    body: location_id,
                };
            } else {
                context.res = {
                    status: 500,
                    body: 'Internal Server Error: Unable to retrieve location_id from the result.',
                };
            }
        } finally {
            await pool.close();
            context.log('Connection pool closed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        context.log.error(error);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: 'Internal Server Error',
        };
    }
};
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully as shown below.

[image]

**Output at browser :**

[image]

**Method-2 :**

***Code :***

```js
const { AzureFunction, Context } = require('@azure/functions');
const { ConnectionPool, sql } = require('mssql');

const config = {
    server: "<server_name>.database.windows.net",
    database: "<db_name>",
    user: "<user_name>",
    password: "<password>",
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        connectTimeout: 30000,
    },
};

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {
        const body = req.body;
        context.log(`Incoming request body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);

        if (!body || !body.someExpectedProperty) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: 'Bad Request: Missing or invalid request body.',
            };
            return;
        }

        const pool = new ConnectionPool(config);

        try {
            await pool.connect();
            context.log('Connected to the database');

            const request = pool.request();
            const query = `EXEC dbo.sp_location_insert @ColumnName = N'${body.someExpectedProperty}'`;
            const result = await request.query(query);
            if (result && result.recordset && result.recordset[0] && result.recordset[0].location_id) {
                const location_id = result.recordset[0].location_id;

                context.res = {
                    status: 201,
                    body: location_id,
                };
            } else {
                context.res = {
                    status: 500,
                    body: 'Internal Server Error: Unable to retrieve location_id from the result.',
                };
            }
        } finally {
            await pool.close();
            context.log('Connection pool closed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        context.log.error(error);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: 'Internal Server Error',
        };
    }
};
```

****Output :****

It ran successfully as shown below.

[image]

I sent the post request in the JSON body in Postman as shown below.

***json:***

```json
{
    "someExpectedProperty": "1"
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great thank you Dasari.  I believe it is using the v3 Node.js model rather than the v4 model.   Is that correct?

Comment: @RossAttrill Attrill yes

Comment: So it doesn't quite answer the question.  The answer might be that it is not possible with v4 model.  But it is a useful answer - thank you Dasari.

Comment: Hi - it doesn't answer the question as the question specifically was 'can this be done with v4'.